# Setting cells equal to other cells based on related values

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to relate, based on how close in time they are, readings that were taken at different times. In two different sheets ("Mass Balance" and "Averages") there is a time column, and I want to copy numbers from "Averages" to paste in "Mass Balance" based on how close these number's times are (see pic).

The part I'm having trouble with is the final If statement. For some reason it's pasting the final value from "Averages" into all the rows in "Mass Balance," instead of pasting the value that has the closest time.

Variable descriptions:

mbv1 & 2 are the initial and final times in "Mass Balance"

mbd1 & 2 are the initial and final rows for mbv1 & 2 in "Mass Balance"

avgd1 & 2 are the initial and final times in "Averages"

[image: Explanation Image]

```
Dim c1 As Double
For o = mbv1 To mbv2
    For n = mbd1 To mbd2
        For m = avgd1 To avgd2
            For i = 0 To 40
                If Abs(Cells(m + i, 1) - o) < Abs(Cells(m + i + 1, 1) - o) Then
                    c1 = i + m
                    Sheets("Mass Balance").Cells(n, 3) = Sheets("Averages").Cells(c1, 4)
                    Sheets("Mass Balance").Cells(n, 10) = Sheets("Averages").Cells(c1, 6)
                Else
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample worksheet that looks like this:

```
 |         A         |         B          | C |       D      |       E       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1| Mass Balance Data | Mass Balance Times |   | Average Data | Average Times |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2|                   |         13         |   |       1      |       10      |
3|                   |         22         |   |       2      |       20      |
4|                   |         31         |   |       3      |       30      |
5|                   |        ...         |   |     ...      |      ...      |
```

Since the code below was done using simple data and in one sheet you will have to change some things for your own code but it worked for me on the data above.
The idea is that there are 2 loops total. You loop through each mass balance time. For each mass balance time loop through the entire average time column. Once you find the closest time that matches mass balance time, copy the data value and paste it in mass balance data for that particular time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub dataCollect()

'MBr stands for Mass Balance Row
'Each of these represent the row and col of a cell with time values
Dim MBr, MBc As Integer
Dim AVGr, AVGc As Integer
Dim minRow, minCol As Integer

Dim minDiff As Integer
Dim mbTime As Integer
Dim avgTime As Integer

Dim currDiff As Integer

'start off with beginning row and column of mass balance times and average times
MBc = 2
AVGc = 5
For MBr = 2 To 10

    'set minDiff to be a really high number
    'so that the first difference value between average and mass balance times
    'will be saved as the minimum difference value (used for if statement later)
    minDiff = 10000

    'loop through each average time
    'find and save the row and column of the cell with the closest time to mass balance time
    For AVGr = 2 To 10

        'mass balance time value
        mbTime = Cells(MBr, MBc).Value

        'average time value
        avgTime = Cells(AVGr, AVGc).Value

        'set current difference value
        currDiff = Abs(avgTime - mbTime)

        'if the difference in times is smaller than the last recorded difference
        'then save the row and column of the current average time cell
        'and set the new minimum (minDiff) value to be the current diff (currDiff) value
        If (currDiff < minDiff) Then
            minRow = AVGr
            minCol = AVGc
            minDiff = currDiff
        End If
    Next

    'now set the mass balance value to be the average value with the closest time
    'minCol - 1 and MBc -1     grabs the data value assosiated with that time
    Cells(MBr, MBc - 1) = Cells(minRow, minCol - 1).Value
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So in Sheet "Averages" there are data points in a column, and each data point has a time associated with it (in another column). In Sheet "Mass Balance" there is also a column for time, but the time points are all different from the time points in Sheet "Averages."



Say there is a time in Sheet "Mass Balance" at 12:00:00, and in Sheet "Averages" there is a time at 11:20:00, and 13:40:00. Since 11:20:00 is closer to 12:00:00, I want the data point in Sheet "Averages" that is in the same row as the 11:20:00 point to copy into Sheet "Mass Balance" into the same row as 12:00:00

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how to use your method because "Averages" and "Mass Balance" are two separate sheets. This method would still work for that correct?

Comment: Above you have:  Sheets("Mass Balance").Cells(n,3)  You should be able to use the same notation where I pull    Cells(MBr, MBc - 1)=... would become Sheets("Mass Balance").Cells(MBr, MBc -1)=...  MBr and MBc are just references to the Mass Balance Rows and Columns (specifically the time column and then MBc -1 refers to the data column so just replace that as needed. Since my data sheet has the column at 2 for mass balance times I set MBc=2 above.)